# Two complex integrals of the function $1/z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$ and $\alpha, \beta : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be defined by:
$$\alpha(t):=a\cos(2\pi t)+ia\sin(2\pi t)$$
$$\beta(t):=a\cos(2\pi t)+ib\sin(2\pi t)$$

> Show that $\int_\alpha 1/z \,dz = \int_\beta 1/z \,dz$.

#### Progress

I thought that the first integral can be found as
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2\pi a(i\cos(2\pi t)-\sin(2\pi t))}{a(\cos(2\pi t)+i\sin(2\pi t))}\,dt$$
and similarly for the second integral. But I don't know how to compute these.

Comment: By computing? What have you done so far?

Comment: I thought this: first integral: \int{0}{1} \frac{2*pi*a*(i*cos(2*pi*t)-sin(2*pi*t))}{a(cos(2*pi*t)+isin(2*pi*t))} and idem for the second integral, but i don't know how to compute this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Direct computation

The curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given in the OP can be written as

$$\alpha(t)=ae^{2\pi i t}, $$

and similarly for $\beta$. Then

$$\int_{\alpha} f:=\int_0^1 f(\alpha(t))\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t)dt= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{ae^{2\pi i t}}2\pi ia e^{2\pi i t}dt=2\pi i,$$

and similarly for $\beta$. I used $\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(t)= 2\pi ia e^{2\pi i t}$.
The thesis follows.

- A second approach

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is meromorphic with a pole in $z=0$. The closed curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ describe circles in the complex plane with center $0$. Now use the Cauchy residue theorem.

Comment: Now I have to show that the int 1/(a^2*(cost)^2+b^2*(sint)^2)dt from 0 to 2pi is equal to (2pi)/(ab). How can I do this?